# How to make my discord bot count specific words?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am a total newbie when it comes to programming, but because i own a discord server i got interested in creating my own discord bot. From a tutorial i decided to make it in javascript and so far i've made it to respond to my commands to send back things like "hello". My goal is to make a command that would show how many times did the person say a specific word. How do i approach this? Is it even possible?

Comment: My suggestion is to learn Javascript/NodeJS fully before making a bot, as it's very a very advanced basis of programming, easy to mess up without any prior knowledge of coding.

Answer (score 0):

As [Octogonal T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13937366/octagonal-t) Suggested, getting the hang of JavaScript is a necessity. However I'll provide you this example. This will only be a permessage counter, If you want to set up a counter that updates overtime then you will definitely need to fully learn JavaScript.

Get the content of the message and [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), then use [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return an array of all the matches. Your result will be the [Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of said matches array.

**Inside Your Message Event => Your Command**

```
// Set up the array of user-sent words
const words = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ');

// Define the word you're looking for
const keyWord = 'foo';

// Use Array#filter and Array#length
const countOfWord = words.filter(word => word === keyWord).length;
```

Please check out all of the hyperlinks I have provided.